# Other users are no longer able to verify our Google account using SMS

Tags: google-account, account-recovery, multi-factor-auth

I use a Google account for my association that several of us use. For several years, everything had been working fine. But recently, other users can't click on their phone number to review their code by SMS.

On the **Two-Step Validation** page, where it presents the options you can choose to perform verification, all the SMS verification phone numbers are there but they are now grayed out and can't be clicked on, and each has a note below the phone number ***"Unavailable because you have more secure options"***

All the phone numbers have been verified.

Do you know a solution? In the capture, I can identify myself with the YouTube application but it works for me because I am the account manager. It doesn't work for the other people. I know that Google doesn't intend for people to share an account and not sure if that is the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. App messages should be posted as text, in English, not as images. To get the messages in English look at the screen if it includes a language selector, otherwise chance the account preferences language to English temporarily.

Comment: By the way, Google user accounts are not intended to be shared. While Google doesn't know who is trying to use an account, they use the location, device information among other things to prevent abuses and to make the account safe, for the intended use cases.

Answer (score 1):

## Verification via Device

> *works for me because I am the account manager*

No. You are not the account manager. That is not a thing. You may have channel manager permissions on the association's YouTube channel, but that also is not why you are logged in.

If you are logging into a new device and successfully approving 2FA verification  it is necessarily the case that you are also logged in to a mobile device.

The reason other users can't login is that:

1. Their devices are unverified.
2. There is at least one verified mobile device on the account.
3. Google now defaults to performing account verification on already  verified mobile devices.

On your [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7tqt.png) Google notes that verification via SMS is **Unavailable because you have more secure options** *("Indisponible, car vous disposez d'options plus sécurisées")*. In other words, one or more verified mobile devices.

## One Account/One Owner

The way your association is approaching this is problematic and should be changed.

1. One person (you?) takes responsibility (pseudo-ownership) of the  account. That person becomes the defacto account owner using their contact info and device to secure the account.
2. One or two (maybe not 4...) people have their phone numbers as *recovery* numbers. These can then be used to recover access to the account via SMS if, and only if, the primary device is ever lost or stolen.

The bottom line is that having multiple people logging in as a single user is not reccomended and insecure. Everyone should have their own unique Google account with their own private password. Then, use available tools to collaborate as needed.

## Sharing Gmail Access

If access to that account's messages is required by other users, you can [delegate that access](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en).

You can also choose to provide other Google accounts **send as** (email alias) privileges for that account.

Delegate and **send as** privileges can be combined or shared separately.

## Collaborative Inbox

An additional option is to set up a [Google Group as a collaborative inbox](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/167430?hl=en)

## Sharing YouTube Channel Permissions

YouTube allows a channel's owner to [give other Google accounts channel permissions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9481328?hl=en) such as **Manager** or  **Editor**